# Webpack: Is there a way to register a loader via a plugin?

Tags: webpack, webpack-plugin

I am trying to build something that loads code formats with a llvm frontend into web projects via wasm. For this I need to register a loader for all the file types, but I also need access to the hooks and settings exposed to a plugin.

In short: Is there a way to set up a loader from within a webpack plugin, that involves as little configuration as possible on the user side?